# Has the associative property been generalized to k-ary functions?

Tags: functions, associativity

I've been [exploring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4249395/why-is-the-associative-property-so-special-to-mathematicians?noredirect=1#comment8834248_4249395) why the associative property is so interesting to mathematicians.  Along the way, I have found the rather obvious fact that it only works on binary operations.  It needs a concept of a left operand and right operand in order to discuss how one writes $(x\star y)\star z = x\star (y\star z)$ in our normal string-based notation for algebras.

If I rephrase that binary infix operator $\star$ as a binary function $f$, I would write the same behavior as:
$$f(f(x, y), z)=f(x, f(y, z))$$
Which leads to the question: is there an extension of the associative property which applies to k-ary functions (where k > 2)?  Obviously one could merely invent such a property, but is there one which mathematicians have found worthy to call a "k-ary associate property" or something along that vein?

Comment: See the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265879/ternary-associative-multiplication) for example.

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, I realized that I had already found the answer, but had merely misinterpreted the notation.  Ifound [n-ary associative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ary_associativity), such as the ternary associative property:
$$(abc)de=a(bcd)e=ab(cde)$$

I had interpreted that as a weakened version of the associative property over binary operations which simply required groupings 3.  Closer reading shows that it actually was an operation over a ternary function $f$:
$$f(f(a, b, c), d, e) = f(a, f(b, c, d), e) = f(a, b, f(c, d, e))$$